# Django {% url %} behaving strangely

Tags: django

Can someone explain why this works:

```
<li><a href="/index/">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="/project/">PROJECTS</a></li>
```

While this doesn't:

```
 <li><a href="{% url projects.views.index %}">HOME</a></li>
 <li><a href="{% url projects.views.project %}">PROJECTS</a></li>
```

I get a 500 error with *ImportError at /index/ No module named project* however I'm not trying to import project anywhere. (I am importing Project, which has been importing fine for days, and works fine when I don't use {% url %} style links). I've seen a number of answers here and blog posts elsewhere suggesting that {% url %} is a bad idea. I'm happy to stop using them if necessary, but for the life of me can't see where the error is coming from.

Contents of urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings

from django.views.static import *

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^index/', 'projects.views.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^login/', 'project.views.login', name='login'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<project_id>\d+)/$', 'projects.views.project', name='project'),
    url(r'^project/', 'projects.views.project', name='project'),

    url(r'^sched/(?P<project_id>\d+)/$', 'projects.views.schedule'),
    url(r'^luminaires/(?P<project_id>\d+)/$', 'projects.views.luminaires'),
    url(r'^luminaire/(?P<project_id>\d+)/(?P<luminaire_id>\d+)/$', 'projects.views.luminaire'),
    url(r'^deleteproject/(?P<project_id>\d+)/$', 'projects.views.deleteproject', name = 'deleteproject'),


    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'relume.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^relume/', include('relume.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes':True}),
)
```

Comment: Here's the urlconf by the way: url(r'^index/', 'projects.views.index', name='index'),

Comment: Try just `index` instead of `projects.views.index` there in the url in template.

Comment: Tried. Same error. Is using just index dependant on having the name='index' parameter in the url conf?

Comment: Yes, If you pass a name in the url conf, then you can use that name in the url in template.What version of django are you using?

Comment: And please post you whole `urls.py` file.

Comment: urls.py contents added above. Using Django 1.4

Comment: Are you having two app named `projects` and `project` ?? If not I thin k the error is just a typo. You may have to use `projects` instead of `project` in the `login` url line.

Comment: Apologies for wasting your time. Typo was a lot easier to spot in code on SO than in editor. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at your `urls.py` file, it seems you have a typo in the login's line of urls where you have used `project` instead of `projects`.